# Open certain files in a workspace as read-only in VS Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working on a typescript project using Visual Studio Code. I have a workflow in which a gulp task will copy a code into a target folder. Copied file will be used by the respective files in the destination folder using imports.

eg. Folder structure

common

server/src

client/src/app

All the files in common will be copied into server/src/common and client/src/app/common

In the server/src/test.ts file, I will add reference to the copied files as follows.

```
import { CommonClass } from './common/commonClass'
```

Everything works perfectly fine. The problem occurs when I decide to go to the definition of the imported class 'CommonClass' by pressing F12.

This will open up the copied file and not the one in the source "common" folder. I would like to restrict this opened file to be in read-only mode, so that I do not make changes. The changes will be replaced by the gulp task in time.

Is there any way to achieve this using some extensions or workspace settings in Visual Studio Code?

Tried to use gulp-chmod to make the destination files are read-only, but ran into issue when the typescript compiler is trying to access them during build.

Comment: (Better late than never) Not an answer, but a solution could be creating a symlink instead of copying the files. I currently have this in my multi-module project and it works well, as editing the referenced file will edit the original one.

Comment: You could try hiding them with `"files.exclude"` in your workplace settings. e.g. `"files.exclude": { "**/dist/**/*": true }`

Comment: What you need is: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161715
which will allow you to specify semantically read-only files, independent of the the filesystem/chmod attributes.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but if you are using something like webpack or tsc for both projects, you may be able to just link to the folder directly from your code. If you setup an alias in webpack it could look something like `import { CommonClass } from 'common/commonClass';`. Webpack would then compile the contents of the common module into your dist folder. I've successfully used this process in the past for code shared between client and server.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.79 introduces [a feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_readonly-mode) to mark specific files and folders as read-only

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension to do this simply: [Read-only: Non-workspace Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.read-only-non-workspace). It will set non-workspace files to `read-only` automatically, no need to trigger a command.

All non-workspace files will be set to read-only (for the session only, not a file-system property change) on starting or reloading vscode or when dragging a file from the system file explorer or otherwise opening a non-workspace file, such as `Open with...` from your File Explorer.

[image: demo of read-only extension opening file from system File Explorer]

Answer (score -1):

Why not structure this multi-project solution as a monorepo with a single node_modules to service all projects, and your common code held in a shared library project which other projects can simply import?

This would not only prevent you from having multiple copies of the same file in many places (some of which you don't want to edit), but would relieve the need for you to use Gulp as a task runner to copy the files around.

Checkout https://nx.dev