# Import types of one of two files (conditionally)

Tags: typescript

How can I `export type * from "../client/types"` --=OR=-- fallback to `export type * from "@api/types"`? ... or make them conditional - whatever gets the job done.

Let's say I have two projects:  `server` and `client`.  API types are shared and defined in `client`.  The API types from `client` get published during build:  `npm publish @api/types`.  The `server` project consumes them.

In the `server` project, I have `apiTypes.ts` which would do the `export type * from ...` statements, and anything else in the `server` project would `import ... from ./apiTypes`

I am looking for a convenient way to develop server + client locally.

The most cumbersome way:

- Always `export type * from "@api/types"`
- If a type changes, I must update package.json and publish a new @api/types, then upgrade the server to use the new package.  Not ideal, especially considering there's merges and pipelines involved, not to mention published packages that are still being developed.

A less cumbersome way:

- Have both `export type * from "...` statements, and just comment one out during dev, and comment out the other when done

This would be fine.  If I forget to uncomment, the pipeline build would fail, reminding me to fix it - no harm done.

But is there a way to simply export the types from a file locally if it exists (or if an environment variable is set), and otherwise export the types from the published package?

Just trying to set up the most convenient experience for devs.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer I gave on another question regarding sharing some common code between a client and server project:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77835121/9530594

With a monorepo structure, you wind up having a path alias to the shared lib which looks like an npm package library reference.  You don't have to re-publish with npm every time your lib changes (unless projects outside your monorepo are actually consuming the library as an npm package).

Comment: Thanks for this.  It's a possible alternative strategy for sure.  But I'll wait and see if there are any answers to the original question.

Comment: @Josh no problem.  I'm wondering if you might be able to flip some things around and use the dynamic `import()` as documented in the mdn web docs at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Any chance you could post a link to a repo of your project?